# How to uninstall Git (Apple Git-75) from Mac?

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I am unable to uninstall Git from my Mac. I am running macOS Sierra. I have tried all solutions available, but can't seem to figure out how to uninstall Git from my Mac.

Here is the screenshot of the current version of Git installed on my Mac.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgrAL.png]

Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

#### just install the latest git by brew

```
brew install git
```

then

```
PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

the new git version will replace apple git as default

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing for you to do. The git you refer to is a part of the operating system. It's not user-installable. You **do not** want to un-install it.

If you want a different version, install it using e.g MacPorts or homebrew and use `port select git` or `brew link`, respectively, to choose the preferred version.

Comment: I want to install and use Homebrew Git.

Comment: @CaptainCold You don't need to uninstall the system Git to do that.

Comment: @duskwuff Yeah. I know. I have two versions of Git installed, the System Git, and Homebrew Git. Now, the problem is that how to use Homebrew Git as default when the System Git is already there.

Comment: @CaptainCold You need to 1. Have [homebrew's binary in your path before system path](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/93179/45058). Use e.g. `brew doctor` to verify that (IIRC). 2. Use `brew link` to select whether you want to use system git or git from any particular brew. **Or** you can add an alias to the desired git in your `.profile`.

Comment: @KubaOber Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem today. I wanted to use the latest [git](https://git-scm.com/download/mac) version as default instead of Apple Git. After a couple of hours, here is what helped me -

1. Install latest (or whichever you want) version of [git](https://git-scm.com/download/mac)
2. Make note of the location where new git binary got downloaded. In my case, it got downloaded at `/usr/local/git/bin/git`
3. Backup Apple Git binary to some location (just in case)

   `$ sudo cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git /tmp/git-apple`
4. Overwrite system's git with above downloaded git binary

   `$ sudo cp /usr/local/git/bin/git /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git`
5. Verify the git version now -

   `$ git --version`

Hope this helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but for me on a Mac running macOS 13.2.1 Ventura…

## `/usr/local/bin/git`

It seems that `/usr/local/bin/git` is user installed. In a terminal, type `which git` to see if you have this. This *git* can be uninstalled. I found shortcuts there. I context-clicked on one to find original.

By digging into the orignial folders I found a `uninstall.sh`. Drag that to a Terminal.app window, and hit Return to execute. The script confirms your desire to uninstall `git`. Proceed, wait a moment, and Poof!. Gone.

Now run `which git` again. In my experience,  it switch to now reporting a different installation of git: `/usr/bin/git`.

## `/usr/bin/git`

In contrast, `/usr/bin/git` seems to be installed by Apple and cannot (or apparently, *should not*) be removed.

---

This purge enabled my [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) IDE to successfully install Git so that I might access GitHub from within an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) project.

Before the purge, IntelliJ reported errors after trying to install Git for its own use.

Answer (score -1):

To remove all components of git from MAC

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ sudo rm -rf git*
```

Answer (score -1):

Hacky way to solve this, add `alias git=/usr/local/bin/git` to ~/.zshrc